# A Generic Function to Process JSON Data

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

**What is the best way to generically handle processing returned JSON data and sticking it into an object for use elsewhere (primarily as a way to extract a few bits of data from a huge JSON object)? Data that could have objects for property values (or not)?**

I have several chunks of code that return some JSON, process that JSON to extract needed value from it and then prepare that data for output to the DOM.

Data can be returned similar to the following:

```
data = [ { "vehiclename" : "Focus",
    "vehiclemake" : "Ford",
    "id" : "123456",
    "val" : { "name" : "meh",
        "datestart" : "May 1"},
    "attch":{ "overview":"abc123"}
}]
```

The code I create to access this data looks like:

```
var processFoo = function (data) {
        var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
        var returnData = [];
        var len = parsedData.length;
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            returnData[i] = {
                'name':parsedData[i].val.name,
                'date':parsedData[i].val.datestart,
                'overview':parsedData[i].attch.overview === '' ? '-' : parsedData[i].attch.overview,
                'id':parsedData[i].id
            };
        }

        return returnData;
    };
```

Other code does almost the same thing with different datasets, only changing the properties and values used. For example with data like:

```
data = [ { "cost" : "1000",
    "vehiclemake" : "Ford",
    "id" : "123456",
    "val" : { "model" : "meh",
        "make" : "May 1"}
}]
```

I would do:

```
var processBar= function (data) {
        var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
        var returnData = [];
        var len = parsedData.length;
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            returnData[i] = {
                'model':parsedData[i].val.model,
                'make':parsedData[i].val.make,
                'cost':parsedData[i].cost === '' ? '-' : parsedData[i].cost,
                'id':parsedData[i].id
            };
        }

        return returnData;
    };
```

What I want to do is create something generic to handle this processing, so that I don't end up with 10 different functions that only vary in the object properties and values they create.

I thought I could create a generic function to process this data and it would work something like:

```
var keys = ['model, 'make', 'cost', 'id'];
var values = ['vehiclename', 'vehiclemake', 'totalcost', 'id'];
var gd = genericProcessData(data, keys, values);
```

And while I can make something that works, to a certain extent, it requires that the values only be one "level" (don't know the correct word to use here) deep in the object property hierarchy.

So data formatted like:

```
[{ "vehiclename" : "Focus",
    "vehiclemake" : "Ford",
    "id" : "123456"
}]
```

will work.

However data formatted like:

```
[{ "vehiclename" : "Focus",
    "vehiclemake" : "Ford",
    "id" : "123456",
    "values" : { "company_id" : "0",
        "completed_by_email" : ""},
}]
```

Is a problem because I do not know how to access the data that is deeper in the object with my generic function (ex. `values.company_id`

Trying to access it like the following only works if the data is one level deep as it is in the first data example… when properties have further objects as their values I do not know how to access these dynamically:

var genericProcessData = function(data, propertykeys, propertyvals){
        var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
        var returnData = [];
        var len = parsedData.length;
        var klen = propertykeys.length;
        var i, j;

```
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        returnData[i] = {};
        for(j = 0; j < klen; j++) {
                returnData[i][propertykeys[j]] = parsedData[i][propertyvals[j]];
        }
    }

    return returnData;
};
```

So the above will be able to access vehiclemake, vehiclename or id but unable to access anything in values:

```
 **[{ "vehiclename" : "Focus",
        "vehiclemake" : "Ford",
        "id" : "123456",
        "values" : { "company_id" : "0",
            "completed_by_email" : ""},
    }]**
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to flatten and otherwise manipulate an object. Underscore (http://underscorejs.org/) is very good at this.

Comment: Ahhh! That looks very promising.